# Hibernate : closing the session factory

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a jboss application (web service producer/consumer) that incorporates hibernate. It works fine normally. When my controller  starts I initialize hibernate and create a `sessionfactory`. 
I then use this `sessionfactory` to generate sessions when performing various database transactions. 
We are good.

My problem comes after a certain period of inactivity on the controller (say when the external web service does not pass any data for a while and then try to send some data). Looks like my `sessionfactory` is closed.

- No error reported in log trace
- This is happening only in my production environment not in non-production.

dbContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.databaseurl}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.xxxx.interceptor.MyInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors> 
    <bean id="projectDao"  class="com.promo.dao.ProjectDaoImpl"/>
    <bean id="project"  class="com.promo.domain.Project"/>
</beans>
```

DAO

```
public class ProjectDaoImpl implements ProjectDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

                    @Override
                public NetworkDetails getNetworkDetails(NetworkInput networkInput) {

                    Session session = null; 
                    NetworkDetails networkDetails = new NetworkDetails();
                    try
                    {
                        int sizeList = 0;
                        String networkName = "";
                        networkName = networkInput.getNetworkName();
                        networkName = networkName.toUpperCase();                

                        BigDecimal autoPurge = new BigDecimal(0);
                        BigDecimal PROJECTSILOAssetId = new BigDecimal(0);
                        BigDecimal dropBoxId = new BigDecimal(0);
                        StringBuilder hqlQuery = null;
                        Query query = null;     
                        List<Object[]> networkDetailsList = null;

                        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

                        hqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
                        hqlQuery.append(" SELECT ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECT_INSTANCE_URL, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECT_TOKEN, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" SEND_MESSAGE_NEW_VERSIONS, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" SEND_MESSAGE_CHANGED_VERSION, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" HOST_CONTEXT, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" AUTO_PURGE_DELAY, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECTSILO_APIKEY, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECTSILO_USERNAME, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECTSILO_PASSWORD, ");             
                        hqlQuery.append(" DROPBOX_TEAMTOKEN, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" DROPBOX_ACCOUNTEMAIL, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" DROPBOX_TARGETURL, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" SEND_MSG_DELIVERED_VERSIONS, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" VERSION_AUTO_PURGE, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" PROJECTSILO_ASSET_ID, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" DROPBOX_SHARED_URL, ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" DROPBOX_ID ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" FROM MAPPINGS_MASTER ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" WHERE ");
                        hqlQuery.append(" ORGANIZATION_ID IN ( SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID FROM ORGANIZATION WHERE UPPER(ORGANIZATION_NAME) = :networkName AND DELETED_FLAG = 'N' )");
                        logger.debug("query getNetworkDetails:::---------> " +hqlQuery );
                        if (session!=null)
                            {
                            query = session.createSQLQuery(hqlQuery.toString());    
                            query.setParameter("networkName", networkName);
                            }
                        if (query!=null)
                            {
                                networkDetailsList =  query.list();
                            }

                        if ( networkDetailsList!=null){
                            logger.debug("if loop");

                            sizeList = networkDetailsList.size();
                                        for(Object[] obj : networkDetailsList){

                                            logger.debug("Inside the for loop in networkDetailsList dao layer");
                                            if (obj[0]!=null)
                                            {
                                            networkDetails.setPROJECT_URL((String)obj[0]);}
                                            else
                                            {
                                                networkDetails.setPROJECT_URL("");
                                            }


                                        }

                            }


                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                        session.clear();
                        session.close();
                    }

                    return networkDetails;
                }
```

}

Comment: It might help if you'd show code.  In my experience, you typically create a `SessionFactory` at application bootstrap and reuse the same `SessionFactory` to create sessions since bootstrapping a `SessionFactory` can be quite expensive.

Comment: and what is the actual stack trace. Looks like.. can mean many things..

Comment: Thanks, posted the code here.